# Restricting SQL Server access for Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 running on a dedicated server together with a web site hosted on that same server.  We now wish to access the SQL Server databases from an Azure Web API, however for security reasons we require that the databases remain on the dedicated server and aren't moved to SQL Azure.  I have been able to expose the SQL Server using SSL only external connections.  I have also been able to use a firewall rule to lock down the port so that only I can connect from my IP address for testing it out.  Is there a way to lock it down so that only my Azure Web API (or potentially multiple instances of it) can connect to the databases?